# Is it valid to say that kruskal is Theta(mlogn) instead of O(mlogn)?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, complexity-theory

Does kruskal have a lower bound? Since we sort the edges ..
Everywhere I see O(mlogn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kruskal's algorithm proceeds in two stages:

1. Sort the edges by weight from lowest to highest.
2. Add edges back when they don't close a cycle.

The runtime cost of step (1) depends on what sorting algorithm is used. For example, if you use quicksort, then step (1) will take Ω(m log n) time and O(m<sup>2</sup>) time. If you use mergesort, then step (1) will take Ω(m) time and O(m log n) time. If you use a radix sort, and the edge weights range from 0 to U, then step (1) will take Θ(m log U) time. But because this depends on the sorting algorithm used and the particulars of the data fed into the algorithm, we can't give a strong lower bound. (The best lower bound we could give would be Ω(m), since you have to process each edge at least once.)

The runtime cost of step (2) is O(mα(m, n)), where α(m, n) is the Ackermann inverse function, and there is a matching lower bound of Ω(mα(m, n)) here.

So overall the cost of Kruskal's algorithm is "the cost of sorting, plus Θ(mα(m, n))."

Comment: Without qualification, Ω complexity is a lower bound on the *worst case* input.  Without any special input constraints, Kruskal's is Ω(m log n)

Comment: I’m not familiar with that convention. Do you have a source for or example of that?

Comment: It's not hard to find references on both sides -- that's the problem with an appeal to authority in the internet age.  If we're less sloppy in our notation, though, it's apparent.  O(m log n) and Ω(m log n) are *sets of functions* by definition.  When we say that an algorithm is ...one of those sets..., we are saying that if T(n) is the worst-case running time of any particular implementation of that algorithm for an input of size n, then it is an element of one of those sets.  Why would changing the set imply that we're measuring some different function?  Also, nobody cares about best cases.

Comment: I also note that you didn't make the same mistake with union-find.  The best n-sized case of union-find occurs when the graph is a hub with spokes, and that obviously takes O(n) time.